# TypeError: Contract "ERC721Enumerable" should be marked as abstract

Tags: solidity, contract

So I have this error that says (TypeError: Contract "ERC721Enumerable" should be marked as abstract.) and I am unaware on how should I mark the smart contract as abstract. I'm still an absolute beginner so I have no clue how to do certain things yet.
I think I've had this problem before though I have forgotten how I solved it since that was a long time ago and is out of the range of what I can remember.

also here is the program:

````
  pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 import './ERC721.sol';

contract ERC721Enumerable is ERC721 {

    uint256[] private _allTokens;

    // CHALLENGE! Write out mapping yourself!!

    // mapping from tokenId to position in _allTokens array
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _allTokensIndex;
     
    // mapping of owner to list of all owner token ids
    mapping(address => uint256[]) private _ownedTokens;
      
    // mapping from token ID index of the owner tokens list
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _ownedTokensIndex;


    // @notice count NFTs tracked by this contract
    // @return A count of valid NFTs tracked by this contract, where each on of
    // them has an assigned and queryable ower not equal to the zero address


    // @notice Enumerate valid NFT's
    // @dev Throws if '_index" >= 'totalSupply()'.
    // @param _index A couter less than 'totalSupply()'
    // @return The token identifier for the '_index'th NFt,
    // (sort order not specified)

    //function tokenByIndex(uint256 _index) external view returns (uint256);

    // @notice Enumerate NFTs assigned to an owner
    // @dev Throws if '_index' >= 'balanceOf(_owner)' or if
    // '_owner' is the zero address, representing invalid NFTs.
    // @param _owner An address where we are interested in NFTs owned by them
    // @param _index A counter less than 'balanceOf(_owner)'
    // @return The token identifier for the '_index'th NFT assigned to '_owner',
    // (sort order not specfied)

    //function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address _owner, uint256 _index) external view returns (uint256);

    function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721) {
        super._mint(to, tokenId);
        // 2 things!
        // a. add tokens too the owner
        // b. all tokens to out totalSupply - allToken
        _addTokensToAllTokenEnumeration(tokenId);   
        _addTokensToOwnerEnumeration(to, tokenId);
    }

    // add tokens to the _allTokens array and set the position of the tokens indexes

    function _addTokensToAllTokenEnumeration(uint256 tokenId) private {
        _allTokensIndex[tokenId] = _allTokens.length;
        _allTokens.push(tokenId);
    }

    // two function - one that returns token by the index
    // another one thata retruns tokenByOwnerIndex

    function tokenByIndex(uint256 index) public view returns(uint256) {
        // make sure that the undex is not our of bounds of the
        // total supply
        require(index < totalSupply(), 'global index is out of bounds!');
        return _allTokens[index];
    }

    function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address owner, uint256 index) external view returns (uint256){
        require(index < balanceOf(owner), 'owner is out of bounds!');
        return _allTokens[index];

    }

    // return the total supply of the _allTokens array

     function totalSupply() public view returns(uint256) {
        return _allTokens.length;
    }

    function _addTokensToOwnerEnumeration(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
       _ownedTokensIndex[tokenId] = _ownedTokens[to].length;
       _ownedTokens[to].push(tokenId);
    }

    // @notice Transfer owner ship of an NFT -- THE REAL CALLER IS RESPOSIBLE
    // TO CONFIRM THAT '_to' IS CAPABLE OF RECEIVING NFTS OR ELSE
    // THEY MAY BE PERMANENTLY LOST
    // @dev Throws untess 'msg.sender' is the current owner, an authorized
    // operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if '_from' is
    // not current owner, Throws if '_to' is the zero address. Throws if
    // '_tokenId' is not a valid NFT.
    // @param _from The current owner of the NFT
    // @param _to the new owner
    // @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your contract not fully implement all the functions of the ERC721 contract..

Refer

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112724/error-contract-should-be-marked-as-abstract

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol